# How to disable KDE power devil?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, power-management, acpi, acpid

For some reason, KDE's power manager doesn't work for me (laptop doesn't go to sleep properly when the lid is closed).

I would like to use [ACPI events](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#ACPI_events) to handle the power management

However, when I run `systemd-inhibit`, I see that KDE's power devil is a inhibitor

How can I disable Power Devil?

I'm on Arch

Comment: `systemctl --user stop plasma-powerdevil`?  That dropped it from the `systemd-inhibit --list` on this Debian Sid box.  `systemctl` complains about it not having an installation config when I try `disable` though.